# Spring Security Filters

Tags: spring-security

Where can I find **all** of the Spring Security filters of a Java web app?

Looking in `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml`, I see:

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
        <filter>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

But where I can see the whole filter chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What `DelegatingFilterProxy` does is delegate the Filter's methods through to a bean which is obtained from the Spring application context. [...] The bean must implement `javax.servlet.Filter` and it must have the same name as that in the filter-name element.

(Quote from the [reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/security-filter-chain.html#delegating-filter-proxy).)

In the majority of the cases the security [namespace configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ns-config.html) is used to create and configure the filter chain, so I would recommend looking for an xml configuration file that uses the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security` xml namespace. If that's the case, you will also need some understanding of what the namespace configuration does, bacause it creates a number of filters behind the scenes that is not apparent from the DSL-like configuration. You can use the above linked chapter and [this appendix](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/appendix-namespace.html) to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, @zagyi. Side question - where would I find the Spring Security OAuth module in my Spring Security project? I need to modify my `log4j` to print out any log info associated with the OAuth code. Thanks.

Comment: The OAuth module's code resides under two different packages according to the version of the protocol: `org.springframework.security.oauth` and `org.springframework.security.oauth2`.